# How to replace the column values with mode in Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x

I am a beginner in Python. I am having a data set which has 400 variables and 15,000 observations. I need to replace 30 variables with mode.

Example:

```
╔═══════╦════════╦════════╗
║   a   ║   b    ║   c    ║
╠═══════╬════════╬════════╣
║ 1.00  ║ 4.00   ║ 6.00   ║
║ 1.00  ║ 6.00   ║ 7.00   ║
║ 2.00  ║ 2.00   ║ 3.00   ║
║ 3.00  ║ 5.00   ║ 384.00 ║
║ 3.00  ║ 5.00   ║ 5.00   ║
║ 10.00 ║ 5.00   ║ 7.00   ║
║ 99.00 ║ 100.00 ║ 5.00   ║
║ 8.00  ║ 205.00 ║ 6.00   ║
║ 25.00 ║ 303.00 ║ 7.00   ║
║ 26.00 ║ 5.00   ║ 99.00  ║
╚═══════╩════════╩════════╝
```

First, I need to find the mode for each columns
Second, if column >7 then I need to replace the same with mode

Could you please advise me how to create a loop and user-defined function for the same?

I have tried the following,

Finding the mode:

```
print (statistics.mode(df['a'])) # df is my data frame name
```

Replacing the value:

```
df['a'].replace(10, 1).head()
```

I can able to replace only a particular value. But, need to replace all the values if value>7 in all the columns. Could you please advise how to create a user-defined function with loops?